# Extracting integers from a string which has no space

Tags: c++

so i'm currently trying to extract integers from a string. This is what i've done so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string s="VA 12 RC13 PO 44";
    stringstream iss;
    iss << s;
    string temp;
    vector<int> a1;
    int j;
    while (!iss.eof()) {
           iss >> temp;
           if (stringstream(temp)>>j) {
               a1.push_back(j);
           }
           temp="";
   }
}
```

Now, this works fine, but if i change the string to something like s="VA12RC13PO44", aka with no spaces this code doesn't work. Does anyone know how to go about solving this?
Thanks

Comment: `while (!iss.eof()) { iss >> temp; ... }` should be `while (iss >> temp) { ... }` Beyond that, of course your code doesn't work after removing spaces, since `>>` reads **SPACE**-delimited words, and you are reading into a `string`, so `>>` will just consume the whole input on the 1st read. You are going to have to parse the `string` manually to differentiate between digits and non-digits, but how do you expect to handle the `RC13`? You won't be able to skip it anymore, unless you detect the `RC` to skip the `13`, otherwise you would end up processing the `13` like any other number

Comment: Why are you removing the spaces in the first place?

Comment: I think it will be easier to use `std::string` only

Comment: What kind of result do you want from parsing `VA12RC13PO44`? Do you want to have each group of consecutive digits parsed as an integer?

Answer (score 0):

There are really many many possible solutions. It depends on how advanced you are. Personally I would always use a `std::regex` approach for such tasks, but this is maybe too complicated.

A simple handcrafted solution could be this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
    std::string s = "VA 12 RC13 PO 44";
    std::vector<int> a;

    // We want to iterate over all characters in the string
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size();) {

        // Basically, we want to continue with the next character in the next loop run
        size_t increments{1};

        // If the current character is a digit, then we convert this and the following characters to an int
        if (std::isdigit(s[i])) {
            // The stoi function will inform us, how many characters ahve been converted.
            a.emplace_back(std::stoi(s.substr(i), &increments));
        }
        // Either +1 or plus the number of converted characters
        i += increments;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So, here we check character for character of the string. If we find a digit, then we build a substring of the string, starting at the current character position and hand it of to `std::stoi` for conversion.

`std::stoi` will convert all characters it can get an convert it to an int. If there is a non-digit character, it stops conversion and informs on how many characters have been converted. We add this value to the current position of the evaluated character, to avoid to convert the digits from the same integer substring over and over again.

At the end, we put the resulting integer into the vector. We use `emplace_back` to avoid unnecessary temporary value.

This will of course work with or without blanks.